# ionic 2 facebook error logging

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm integrating with facebook for application users to sign in with facebook.
I'm testing the documentation code for ionic 2 but it's not working right every time it drops the error condition. Is there anything else to be done?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RecuperarSenhaPage } from '../recuperar-senha/recuperar-senha';
import { CadastroUsuarioPage } from '../cadastro-usuario/cadastro-usuario';
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private _fb: Facebook) {
    }

    loginFacebook() {

        this._fb.login(['email'])
            .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
            .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', JSON.stringify(e)));

    }

}
```

Comment: what `error` you got in `JSON.stringify(e)` ?

Comment: Nothing is coming back
The return is like this = {}